# Hit Vue client side route directly from URL hosted with Kubernetes/ALB Ingress

Tags: amazon-web-services, vue.js, kubernetes, amazon-eks, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a few applications hosted on a single `Amazon Load Balancer`, at different endpoints on the `ALB` etc. This is server and generated through `Kubernetes EKS`.

```
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: ssl-redirect        
              servicePort: use-annotation
          - path: /a/*
            backend:
              serviceName: service-1
              servicePort: 8080
          - path: /b/*
            backend:
              serviceName: service-2
              servicePort: 8085
```

For the `/*` path, I have it route to a `Vue UI` application.

This application has a few routes, with client side routing. These routes work fine when done through the `UI`. I want to be able to link directly to these client side routes through the URL bar, or at least redirect to the root `UI`. However, when I try to hit it directly, and just route to the `UI` component in the ingress:

```
          - path: /path1/*
            backend:
              serviceName: ui
              servicePort: 80
          - path: /path2/*
            backend:
              serviceName: ui
              servicePort: 80
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: ui
              servicePort: 80
```

The regular `UI` route still works, however `/path1` and `/path2` return 404. The other applications in this ingress return fine (`/path a` and `/path b`, `/service-1` and `/service-2`).

Answer (score 1):

Server-side and client side routings are completely different.

You want to make server-side routing. I.e, server-side rules should exist.
Server app doesn't know neither `/path1` nor `/path2`. Therefore, you get `404` from the server.

Comment: The server should know, and point to the UI service, as I have defined the endpoints in the ingress spec (I have several others that link to unrelated services that work).

Comment: Well, would you please provide the `ingress` configs too?